# Difference between Facebook Graph API page/posts and page/feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mern

I am using Facebook Graph API in my MERN App. I am fetching all posts of page using this edge.

```
GET
{facebook.developer.url}/{page-id}/posts
headers : {page-access-token}
```

But there is another edge is feed like this

```
GET
{facebook.developer.url}/{page-id}/feed
headers : {page-access-token}
```

Both are showing same output. Can anyone tell what's the exact difference between them?

I tried by calling both API's but giving same response.
More I have researched about these edges but didn't get it

Comment: Facebook is saying this about posts:
This Page's own Posts, a derivative of the /feed edge.

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page)